# Volume generated by revolving the region bounded by the curve $y=x^2+1$ and the line $y=-x+3$ about the $y$ axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

**Question:- Find the volume of the solid of revolution generated by revolving the region bounded by the curve $y=x^2+1$ and the line $y=-x+3$ about the $y$- axis.**

[image]

The region on the right when revolved is overlaped by the region on left when revolved,So the volume is same as revolving the left region about y axis.

$$V=\pi \int_{1}^{3} (y-1) \mathrm {dy}+\pi \int_{3}^{5} (y-1)-(3-y)^2 \mathrm {dy}=\frac{16\pi}{3}$$

Is the above integral for calculating volume correct?

Comment: Usually overlapped regions are not well defined as solids of revolution, is this how your specific class told you to address the situation?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi Orignal question has x-axis but I wanted to know what happens if we rotate it about y-axis.

Comment: Then you can't, it's not well defined. If you want to practice, I suggest rotating it about one of the lines $x=\pm 2$

Comment: There are $two$ rotatable  regions, bounded by the blue &  red lines and the y-axis before revolving .

Comment: @Narasimham Yes but smaller region overlaps with the bigger region while rotating.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the volumes do not overlap.